# Restriction to entered values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My question: i have text field size is 110 character and i have one condition like below

```
IF :blk.item = 'OTH' then 
  do not allow to enter more than 100 character;
END IF;
```

if the field reached 100 char then it should not allow to enter next character.

How to use that while running time in oracle? is there any way to avoid length of the field at run time, thanks for your valuable answer.

i have used/tried trigger 'when-validate-item' for that item with the below code,

```
IF :blk.item = 'OTH' then 
  if length(:blk.item1)> 100 then 
     raise form_trigger_failure;
  end if;
END IF;
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constraint check. See this example below and change it to your needs:

```
create table test (
   value varchar2(10),
   item varchar2(3)
);

alter table test add constraint ck_item_size 
  check ( (item = 'OTH' and length(value)<=8) or (item != 'OTH') );


insert into test values ('12345678', 'OTH'); --will work

insert into test values ('blahblah', 'BLA'); --Will work

insert into test values ('blahblahbl', 'BLE');  --will work

insert into test values ('123456789', 'OTH');  --will not work
```

See it on fiddle, work examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df281

For Wont work example paste the last line on fiddle and try to build.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer, I have tried your query but this is not working at runtime in Oracle application..

Comment: Then i think i did not understand your explanation. What are you want to mean when you say 'at runtime'? As I understand runtime is when the application is running and a constraint check is the first check that can be done on a table...